# ruby yaml don't remove header %YAML 1.1

Tags: ruby, header, yaml

I have a array in ruby named array, I aded value into yaml file, but after in file.yml, it remove me %YAML 1.1, so I won't

```
yaml_string = File.read "file.yaml"
data = YAML.load yaml_string
array.each do |value|
        data["title"] <<"- "+value+"\n"
end
output = YAML.dump data
File.write("file.yaml", output)
```

before execution, the header is present, but after execution it remove it (%YAML 1.1) and all lines comment with #, so I won't

Comment: Just use the YAML. load_file function, it will read the file data into a hash. Note in newer rubies, it's in the Psych library https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html

Comment: it does not work Traceback (most recent call last):
 3: from ./test.rb:16:in `<main>'
 2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:497:in `load_file'
 1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:497:in `open'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:497:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Comment: data = YAML.load_file yaml_string

Comment: does the file exist? You may have a relative path error, i.e. file isn't in directory your program is running.

Comment: i already give a full path, above it is just an example, Moreover it tell me file is too long...

Comment: try executing the load file portion within an if File.exists?(filename) (your code here) else raise ArgumentError end guard. usually the error messages are pretty accurate and you should trust them

Comment: it does not catch error

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you're trying to do.

I'm assuming your yaml array of titles matches your array object.

Otherwise you could just use something like [Enum#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) if you just want to map the number of the yaml array to the text.

```
require 'psych'
filename = "sample_yaml.yml"
array = [0, 1, 2, 3]

if File.exists?(filename)
    puts "File exists. :) Parsing the yaml file."
    yaml = Psych.load_file(filename)
    array.each do |value|
        yaml[value]["title"] << " - #{value}" # find the title that matches the index number of array
    end
else
    raise ArgumentError, "bad file name"
end
puts "Outputting to reformatted yaml file"
File.open("reformatted_file.yaml", 'wb') {|f| f.write "%YAML 1.1\n" + Psych.dump(yaml)}
```

assuming yaml file like such

```
---
- title: zero
- title: one
- title: two
- title: three
```

Outputs

```
---
- title: zero - 0
- title: one - 1
- title: two - 2
- title: three - 3
```

Comment: nope, my initial have contain
%YAML 1.1
---
- title:

but after code execution I have only

----
- title:

I don't want to remove %YAML 1.1

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that. I think you're being too literal in your thinking though as that directive is introduced for yaml 1.2. Ruby doesn't technically support it yet. Per @tenderlove https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/253#issuecomment-156169539 so libyaml only supports 1.1 currently. This will become an option when libyaml supports 1.2. from the libyaml docs... "version_directive - the version specified with the %YAML directive; the only valid value is 1.1; may be NULL." https://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML